# Trying to install Angular 2 for a past project

Tags: angular, npm

I know running `npm install @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.33.1` will build Angular 2.4.1. However, after running it, it shows it has many vulnerable packages, and I can't `ng build` or `ng serve`. It said I need to `install ng-common`. However, if I install ng-common, I still can't `ng build` or `ng serve`, I guess it is because they can only recognize `angular.json`, but for Angular 2, it only has `angular-cli.json`.

I need Angular 2 to run my source code. What should I do?

This is my `package.json` file. I've already run `npm install`, but it seems it didn't install the shown version of Angular CLI.

```
{
  "name": "oj-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular/cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "ace-builds": "^1.2.8",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: *it shows it has many vulnerable package* yes, this is because it does. If you use old packages, that's what happens

Comment: _I've already run npm install, but it seems it didn't install the shown version of Angular CLI._ and what version was installed then? Assuming that `npm install` correctly completed with only warnings, then you should be able to run your project. If one of the security vulnerabilities leaded to a module on which your project depends to be removed, then you will need to update your dependencies accordingly.

Comment: you should update everything to newer versions, except for bootstrap which you should continue to use version 3 because 4 most likely will not be compatible.

Comment: my current `ng -v` output is `Mg++ version:
 Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.)'

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. But my suggestion is to use Angular 8 not 2.